# Why is my Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey userscript not working?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

I am trying to fill the first text input  from this google docs with an email:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ciJJg43i1tB9XhKMjFGZBteQFkH80nvyF1w4EpO7v_c/viewform?edit_requested=true

```
My code is:
window.onload = function() {
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")[0];
    input.focus();
    input.click();
    input.value = "abcd@abcd.com"
}
```

It actually replaces the email, but the grey text that is initially in the input (e.g. "enter your email here") does not disappear. And if I don't manually click the label, google  doesn't recognize that there is an input there.

I tried to  simulate a click but didn't find a working code.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger an input event.

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput")[0];
input.value = "abcd@abcd.com"
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles:true}))
```